# Why am I getting these errors? Illegal start of expression

Tags: java, arrays

Here's my code:

```
public class JavaApplication16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //illegal start of expression, ']' expected, <identifier> expected
       boolean a = groupSum(0, [2,4,8], 10); 
    }

    public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
        if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0);

        if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) return true;
        if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried to look for ways to fix this, but I am just so lost. Please help me debug my code.

Comment: try `boolean a = groupSum(0, new int[]{2,4,8}, 10);` and make the method `static`.

Comment: You get this error because this is not the correct syntax to define an array.

Comment: Here is answer for your next question: [Non-static method/variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2559527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the correct notation to create an array. Creating an array of ints looks like: `new int[]{1, 2, 3}.` Another problem present in your code, is that you are calling a non-static method from a static context. You can fix this by labeling `groupSum` as static.
Here is fixed version of your code:

```
class JavaApplication16 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //illegal start of expression, ']' expected, <identifier> expected
        boolean a = groupSum(0, new int[]{2,4,8}, 10);
    }
    public static boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
        if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0);

        if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) return true;
        if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to work with int arrays.

```
boolean a = groupSum(0, new int[] {2, 4, 8}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to be as the following

1- `new int[]{2,4,8}` to create array arrays of ints

2- change groupSum method to be static or create object form  `JavaApplication16` as the following  `JavaApplication16  ja16= new JavaApplication16(); ja16.groupSum(...);`

You can do the following to fix your issues.

```
 public class JavaApplication16 {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean a = groupSum(0, new int[]{2,4,8}, 10);// new int[]{2,4,8} to create array of ints 
        }

        public static boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {// change the method to be static
            if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0);

            if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) return true;
            if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) return true;

            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation to your answer to clarify what is wrong and how to prevent/fix the problem.

Comment: I changed and added explanations, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the int array as

```
boolean a = groupSum(0, new int[] {2,4,8}, 10);
```

another thing, The method `groupSum` is an instance method, while main is a static method; you cant use instance method inside a static mehod.

You have two solutions for this:

1. Define the `groupSum` method as static.
2. Create object of your class `JavaApplication16` and use its method.
   The code would be like:

   ```
   public class JavaApplication16 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JavaApplication16 ja16 = new JavaApplication16();
      boolean a = ja16.groupSum(0, new int[] {2,4,8}, 10); 
    }

    public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) { 
     if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0); 
     if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) return true; 
     if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) return true;

     return false; 
    } 
   }
   ```